# Is it really a bug in JIT optimization or am I missing something?

Tags: c#, jit

```
[TestFixture]
public class Tests
{
    private class Relay
    {
        public Action Do { get; set; }
    }

    [Test]
    public void OptimizerStrangeness()
    {
        var relay = new Relay();
        var indicator = 0;
        relay.Do = () => indicator++;
        var weak = new WeakReference(relay);

        GC.Collect();

        var relayNew = weak.Target as Relay;
        if (relayNew == null) Assert.Fail();
        relayNew.Do();
        Assert.AreEqual(1, indicator);
    }
}
```

This code fails only in Release mode at `Assert.Fail()` line despite the fact `relay` variable is still in scope and thus we still have strong reference to the instance, so WeakReference must not be dead yet.

UPD: To clarify a bit: I realize that it can be 'optimized away'. But depending on this optimization `indicator` variable would have `0` or `1` value, i.e. we have actual visible change of behavior.

UPD2: From C# language specification, [section 3.9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691138%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> If the object, or any part of it, cannot be accessed by any possible continuation of execution, other than the running of
>   destructors, the object is considered no longer in use, and it becomes
>   eligible for destruction. The C# compiler and the garbage collector
>   may choose to analyze code to determine which references to an object
>   may be used in the future. For instance, if a local variable that is
>   in scope is the only existing reference to an object, but that local
>   variable is never referred to in any possible continuation of
>   execution from the current execution point in the procedure, the
>   garbage collector may (but is not required to) treat the object as no
>   longer in use.

Technically speaking, this object can and will be accessed by continuation of execution and thus can't be treated as 'no longer in use' (actually C# spec says nothing about weak references because it is aspect of CLR and not the compiler - compiler output is fine). Will try to search for memory management info about CLR/JIT.

UPD3: Here is [some info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f144e03t.aspx) on CLR's memory management - section 'Releasing memory':

> ...Every application has a set of roots. Each root either refers to an
>   object on the managed heap or is set to null. An application's roots
>   include global and static object pointers, local variables and
>   reference object parameters on a thread's stack, and CPU registers.
>   The garbage collector has access to the list of active roots that the
>   just-in-time (JIT) compiler and the runtime maintain. Using this list,
>   it examines an application's roots, and in the process creates a graph
>   that contains all the objects that are reachable from the roots.

Variable in question is definitely local variable, hence it is reachable. Thus said, this mention is very quick/vague, so I would be really glad to see more concrete info.

UPD4: From sources of .NET Framework:

```
    // This method DOES NOT DO ANYTHING in and of itself.  It's used to
    // prevent a finalizable object from losing any outstanding references 
    // a touch too early.  The JIT is very aggressive about keeping an 
    // object's lifetime to as small a window as possible, to the point
    // where a 'this' pointer isn't considered live in an instance method 
    // unless you read a value from the instance.  So for finalizable
    // objects that store a handle or pointer and provide a finalizer that
    // cleans them up, this can cause subtle ----s with the finalizer
    // thread.  This isn't just about handles - it can happen with just 
    // about any finalizable resource.
    // 
    // Users should insert a call to this method near the end of a 
    // method where they must keep an object alive for the duration of that
    // method, up until this method is called.  Here is an example: 
    //
    // "...all you really need is one object with a Finalize method, and a
    // second object with a Close/Dispose/Done method.  Such as the following
    // contrived example: 
    //
    // class Foo { 
    //    Stream stream = ...; 
    //    protected void Finalize() { stream.Close(); }
    //    void Problem() { stream.MethodThatSpansGCs(); } 
    //    static void Main() { new Foo().Problem(); }
    // }
    //
    // 
    // In this code, Foo will be finalized in the middle of
    // stream.MethodThatSpansGCs, thus closing a stream still in use." 
    // 
    // If we insert a call to GC.KeepAlive(this) at the end of Problem(), then
    // Foo doesn't get finalized and the stream says open. 
    [System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
    [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
    [MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)] 
    public static extern void KeepAlive(Object obj);
```

See [here](http://sparethought.wordpress.com/2012/08/29/bug-in-cil-optimizations-logic-o_o/) for my investigation in more details, if you're interested.

Comment: Your code here and on your blog post are not identical in a crucial way: here you have `Assert.IsNotNull(relay)` and there you do not. Which have you tested, or have you tested both?

Comment: @Adam Oh, thanks, I copied it from the end of blogpost. Corrected. It should not be there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Even if a variable is in scope, the runtime is free to collect it if it's no longer accessed in any future code path. This is why when debugging an assembly with JIT optimizations in place can give you a message about a variable's value being optimized away even though it's currently in scope.

See item 2 on [3.9 Automatic Memory Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691138%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

To be specific,

> For instance, if a local variable that is in scope is the only existing reference to an object, but that local variable is never referred to in any possible continuation of execution from the current execution point in the procedure, the garbage collector may (but is not required to) treat the object as no longer in use.

This is the crucial point; the object is *considered* to be inaccessible because all strong references to the object (there's only one) are unreachable. Remember that the C# spec will contain information about the language *as well as information about how the compiled code should execute*. Also remember that reachability is not defined by scope. As the spec states, if the compiler and runtime can determine that a variable is not present in any future code path (meaning they are never referenced at all or only referenced in paths that are determined to be unreachable, like `if(false)`), then the variable is considered unreachable and does not count as a strong reference.

While that particular portion of the specification does not state `WeakReference` explicitly, it doesn't need to. You have only one local variable that ever points to that value as far as the compiler is concerned.

`WeakReference` is just another class that takes an object as an argument; from the perspective of the compiler; it has no reason to believe (or make an assumption one way or the other) about whether or not that class holds on to the reference that it's passed. Consider if I had a class like this that was used instead:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(object foo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(foo);
    }
}
```

And in my code I did this:

```
var relay = new Relay();
...
var myClass = new MyClass(relay);
```

I haven't introduced any new strong references to the value I assigned to `relay`, as `MyClass` doesn't hold on to that reference. The fact that `WeakReference` is a "special" class that is designed to give you a reference to an object that *doesn't* count as a strong reference is irrelevant as far as the compiler is concerned.

Reachability is not defined by scope; it's defined by whether or not the variable (not value) in question lies in any possible future code path. As `relay` is not present in any form later in the function, the variable (and thus its reference to the object) is considered unreachable and eligible for collection. This is the reason the `DisableOptimizations` flag exists at the assembly level so that the runtime knows (among other things) to wait until the variable falls out of scope before it's eligible for collection so that it is accessible to the debugger.

Comment: Yeah, my thinking is the same. But this 'optimization' changes code behavior: if it is optimized away - `indicator == 0`, otherwise `indicator == 1`. Optimization like that seems like a bug to me.

Comment: It's not a bug, as you're explicitly telling the runtime not to consider your other reference.

Comment: `relay` is still in scope. It _is_ accessible from line where Assert is. What is going on with WeakReference is not relevant as I see it. Maybe I'm missing something in the specification, but afaik, variable is considered not eligible to GC at least as long as it is accessible and accessibility is defined in terms of scope and not actual usage.

Comment: @IvanDanilov: You are not interpreting correctly. To be clear, *variables* are not collected, *references* (ie the value in a variable) are collected. A reference is eligible for collection once no more strong references to it are available (and no other actions have been taken, such as pinning it or any other GC wizardry). Even if a variable with that value is within scope, if it is never used then it is eligible.

Comment: Any links to actual spec explicitly telling that?

Comment: @IvanDanilov: See item 2 on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691138(v=vs.71).aspx and this very similar question with an identical (if a bit longer) answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660445/when-is-net-object-null-game-for-garbage-collection-does-scope-matter

Comment: To demonstrate the behavior, put a `GC.KeepAlive(relay)` at the end of the method.

Comment: @SomeWritesReserved any mention of the variable will do. The problem is you have to remember to do it explicitly. But thanks anyway, I havent't look to this method before.

Comment: @IvanDanilov: you don't have a mention of the variable, though.  You have a reference that is populated from a `WeakReference` which, by the time you get to it, has been collected.  There's no explicit reference to `relay` when you call GC.Collect().  Consider: if the behaviour you suggest *did* work, then any reference to `weak.Target` would have to keep the object alive - negating the purpose of `WeakReference`.

Comment: @Adam yeah, I agree with you on _what_ is happening. Though I'm interested if it is correct behavior or not. C# spec as I see is not right source here, because it is only producing IL. IL is totally correct. And, regarding optimization in general - optimizations by definition are code transformations that producing _same_ result. Here we see that result is different, thus optimization is incorrect in broad sense. I want to find confirmation either that it is intended behavior or that it is unanticipated problematic case.

Comment: @IvanDanilov: The spec states quite explicitly that a variable that is not present in any possible code paths (ie if you referenced it like this `if(false) { relay... }` would still not be present, as the compiler knows at compile time that the path is unreachable) that it is eligible for collection; can you be specific as to where your hesitance to accept that is coming from, especially given that the behavior described by the spec is exactly the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: By the same logic, if I put for example `GC.KeepAlive(relay)` at the end of the method and later compiler evolves enough to prove that some exception would be thrown earlier in the codepath (even if it is something like `SuccessException` from NUnit) - this `KeepAlive()` would be thrown out of the window and `relay` reclaimed again. Are you considering such inconsistent behavior correct?

Comment: @IvanDanilov: That behavior would be correct because it is entirely consistent; if the variable never further referenced in any reachable code, it's not a strong reference. *`WeakReference` is specifically there for you to maintain a reference to an object that does not impact GC eligibility*.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but there have been multiple comments, quite lengthy explanations, and links to the spec that all explicitly define this behavior that was already borne out of experiment. Even though I would consider the behavior as described to be correct, my opinion on the matter is irrelevant; the spec states what the behavior is, and you're seeing that behavior. I'm not sure what else I or anyone else can say here if you aren't willing to accept those. If you feel it's inconsistent or incorrect, your only real recourse is to file a report on Connect.

Comment: @Adam thanks for your efforts) I will accept your answer after some time if none better appears. Meanwhile I'd like to wait a little.

Comment: @IvanDanilov: To be clear, I wasn't referring to marking my answer as accepted (though that'd be nice, too!), I meant accepting that the observed behavior is in line with what the spec says.

Comment: @Adam After forth update I'm at last sure that this is intended behavior, so marked as correct answer. Cheers)